# Subtracting non-zero elements of a list in Python

Tags: python, list

I have a list `n12`. I want to subtract only non-zero elements of `n12` from `1`. I present the current and expected output.

```
n12=[0,
 0.097055623870192,
 0,
 0.09668483656158318,
 0.09983696710324882,
 0.09905078620023211,
 0.09857192019636203]

n22=[1-i for i in n12]
print(n22)
```

The current output is

```
[1, 0.902944376129808, 1, 0.9033151634384168, 0.9001630328967511, 0.9009492137997679, 0.9014280798036379]
```

The expected output is

```
[0, 0.902944376129808, 0, 0.9033151634384168, 0.9001630328967511, 0.9009492137997679, 0.9014280798036379]
```

Comment: Again, use NumPy, as for your previous question.

Comment: Are you using StackOverflow to write your code? All your questions seem to be about roughly the same piece of code. It's allowed, but a bit odd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an [if-else statement](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#if-statements) in your [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
>>> n12 = [0, 0.097055623870192, 0, 0.09668483656158318, 0.09983696710324882, 0.09905078620023211, 0.09857192019636203]
>>> n22 = [1 - x if x != 0 else 0 for x in n12]
>>> n22
[0, 0.902944376129808, 0, 0.9033151634384168, 0.9001630328967511, 0.9009492137997679, 0.9014280798036379]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use conditions inside your loops.

```
n22=[1-i if i != 0 else i  for i in n12]
```

Check the link for more details.
[Python Conditions](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_conditions.asp)

Answer (score 1):

You can have conditions in a list comprehension as follows:

```
n22 = [0 if e == 0 else 1-e for e in n12]
```